# TS2339 -> Property '_id' does not exist on type 'User'

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb

To start with, I am new in TS

I am trying to create /me endpoint in mongoDB using TS, but getting this error (TS2339) in
`const user = await UserModel.findById(req.user?._id);`

I really appreciate any help!

```typescript
usersRouter.get("/me", JWTAuthMiddleware, async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const user = await UserModel.findById(req.user?._id);
    console.log(user);
    res.send(user);
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
});
```

I was trying to add type any, but it didn't give anything

Comment: At least you need defined an extended type/interface from `Request` with `user` prop and use it with `req`

Comment: I believe you first need to read the JSON from the request: `const data = await req.json();`. Then you will be able to take the rest from it: `data.user?._id`

Comment: @carlosV2 problem with req.user?._id dissapeared, but now json has error ts2339 (Property 'json' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>)

Comment: Do you know where this `Request` type is coming from? It doesn't look like the regular `Request` then. In general, please, could you explain a bit more of the technologies you are using? I get that you are fetching data from MongoDB but, what framework are you using? Any other significant library?